# Accessing getter functions inside a class using pointers

Tags: c++, class, pointers, object, binary-search-tree

I just moved from C to C++ so i'm trying to understand the differences between classes and structs.
I'm building a code that deals with binary search trees and i'm using classes.

```
class Node
{
public:
    // C'tor D'tors
    Node();
    Node(int valinput);
    ~Node();

    // Getters
    Node * getrson() const { return rson; }
    Node * getlson() const { return lson; }
    int getval() const { return val; }

    // Setters
    void setlson(Node* input) { lson = input; }
    void setrson(Node* input) { rson = input; }
    void setval(int input) { val = input; }

private:
    int val;
    Node * lson;
    Node * rson;
};
```

I know I shouldn't access private variables directly, therefore I should use get functions. I'm building recursive functions so I use object pointers:

```
Node* insertion(Node* root,int val);
int checkheight(Node* root);
Node* rotate(Node* root, direction direction);
```

When I want to access the right son of the right son of some node, do I need to write something like:

```
if(root->getrson()->getrson() != nullptr)
```

Will this code work? Is there any "more natural" way of writing it? Should I just use structs instead of classes in this case?

Comment: _"Will this code work? "_ Well, did you try it?

Comment: "understand the differences between classes and structs". None, except struct members are public by default, while class members are private. No other difference. How is this relevant to the question?

Comment: I'm still writing it and I've wondered if i'm not wasting my time over 200 lines of code

Comment: "therefore I should use get functions". Doesn't follow. Actually get funcions are a bad kludge. Yoy should use functions that **provide a meaningful, user-centered interface**. Not functions that expose bare internals of your class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it will work and this is the "natural" way of doing this when you use getter functions.

When you use a struct instead, then the line would not look much different:

```
if(root->rson->rson != 0)
```

To increase the efficiency of the call, you may make the getter functions `inline`. However, most compilers do this implicitly by default for optimization, so there should be no need for it. In that case there is not  overhead in using getter functions.